# How can i install kubernetes on Windows Server 2019 (NOT minikube)

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Guys who can help me? who can show me documentation for installing kubernetes cluster in windows server 2019.

My services all Dotnet and WCF, which is good for kubernetes > Windows or Linux?